Should I use #pragma once directive in a hpp header, knowing well it contains some definitions?
I know there is use case scenario for '#pragma once' in classic .h headers containing only declarations. But I wonder: what about .hpp files which most of the time contain many definitions. Should I still use the directive?

"classic .h headers containing only declarations...." That is not entirely true. They also contain class definitions like class C{void f();};

"what about .hpp files..." There's no difference between .h and .hpp files(apart from the pp ofcourse). Both are used as header files. Your assumptions/understanding seem wrong/inaccurate. *.h or *.hpp for your class definitions

.c vs .cc vs. .cpp vs .hpp vs .h vs .cxx

Your question is based on false premises (1) .h or .hpp  are both "headers" and identical to a compiler (2) A definition is a type of declaration e.g. class C; declares but does not define C but class C{}; both defines and declares it (3) Any "header" may have declarations, including definitions (4) When compiling a source file, diagnosable errors occur if the compiler sees multiple definitions (even if identical) of (almost) anything (5) #pragma once (most modern compilers support it, but NOT standard C++) and include guards (standard) are tools to address such problems
